# Javascript onsubmit causing page to refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Really simple form

```
<form id="addDonor" name="addDonor" onsubmit="addDonor(); return false;" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="sectionHeader">Add New Donor</div>
<div class="formRow"><label>Name</label> <input class="inputText fullTextBar" type="text" name="userName">
<div class="formRow"><button style="margin-left:350px; width: 80px" type="button" class="publish">Add Donor</button></div>
</form>
```

And the addDonor function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addDonor(){    
    alert("test");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Eventually that function will include some jquery ajax to submit the info. But, baby, steps. Right now I can't even get the alert to show up. Also, when I hit "Enter" on my keyboard, the whole page refreshes, when I press "Add Donor" nothing happens.

I'm sure it has to be a simple problem. I think it's one of those things that I just need someone else's eyes to point out.

Comment: Your button doesn't have an `onclick` function. Another alternative would be to replace the entire `<button>` tag with `<input type="submit" value="Add Donor" .../>`

Comment: You explicitly set up the button to be **not** a submit button: `type="button"`. Remove that and the button will work. See @Dennis' answer regarding the handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try assigning the onsubmit event in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("addDonor").onsubmit = function () {
    alert("test");
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that your function is named addDonor and your element is addDonor.  Every element with an id has an object created under `document` to identify it.  Try `alert(addDonor)` in the inline onsubmit to see that it alerts an HTML element, not a function.  Inline functions execute in a scope chain inside document, so addDonor points to document.addDonor before it reaches window.addDonor (your function).

Comment: @Felix That works too.  It's just a personal preference as to whether or not you like inline javascript.  That was just the first thing I fixed before I remembered a) inline js runs in the document scope and b) elements with ids get added underneath `document`

Comment: It was as simple as I thought it might be. Never ran into this problem before. Thanks for explaining it so well.

Answer (score 1):

you should change your `<button>` to an `<input type="submit">` (as @fireshadow52 suggested) that should fix your problem. you should try the [Wc3 Schools online javascript tester](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit) to try out simple javascripts before you put it in a page, or any other one that you prefer. google has something along these lines. also, you can normally try the javascript console on your respective browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your button is explicitly set to `type="button"`, which won't make it submit the form. Change it to `<button type="submit">`, or to `<input type="submit">` if you prefer (I like the styling options of `<button>` myself).